# How can I check for a string inside an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to check if 'reply' exists In my arraylist, however when I run my program it doesn't work and I'm kinda lost. If the reply exists in my arraylist, I want it to swap that element with the last element. I tried using the .matches class aswell, but that didn't work.

```
case 2: 
        System.out.println("What employee do you want to remove, Enter full name: ");

        String reply = input.next();

        for(String checkName : EmployeeNameList)

            if(checkName.equalsIgnoreCase(reply)){

                swapByIndex(EmployeeSalaryList, swapList(EmployeeNameList,reply));

            }

            break;
```

These are my swap methods.

```
public static<T>int swapList(ArrayList<T> list, T reference){
    T  t = null;
    T i;

    for(T ref : list){
        if(ref.equals(reference)){
            t = ref;
        }

    }

    i= list.get(list.size()-1);
    list.set(list.indexOf(t),i);
    list.set(list.size()-1,t);

    return list.indexOf(t);
}
public static<T> void swapByIndex(ArrayList<T> list, int index){
    T t;
    t = list.get(list.size()-1);
    list.set(index, t);
    list.set(list.indexOf(t), list.get(index));


}
```

Comment: It might help if you actually told us *what* error you get. Instead of just saying you get one.

Comment: Yeah my bad, at the moment I don't get an error, It just doesn't work

Comment: Define "doesn't work" - what does it do right now, and what did you expect it to do instead?

Comment: Your edit doesn't really help because you don't explain what "didn't work" means. Please be more specific about what the problem is here.

Comment: I expected the program to check if the string reply exists in my arraylist, if it does, then I wanted it to swap that element with the last element.

Comment: What does it do instead? Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using already defined methods in list

```
if(EmployeeNameList.contains(reply)){
                EmployeeNameList.set(EmployeeNameList.indexOf(reply), list.get(list.size()-1));
                EmployeeNameList.set(EmployeeNameList.size()-1, reply);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method contais of the ArrayList

Example:

```
    public void containsExample(){
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
    array.add("example1");
    array.add("example2");
    array.add("example3");
    if(array.contains("example1")){
        System.out.println("example1 exists");
    }
}
```